# dygraph retrieve data from ajax

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

generate.php will extract data from mysql in `json` format.

then graph.php will request to generate.php through `ajax` for the `json` data.

how can i use this `json` data to feed `dygraph` data,

example dygraph code.

```
g3 = new Dygraph(
document.getElementById("graphdiv3"),
//"temperatures.csv",
          [              //this part i need to change with ajax request data
            [1,10,100],
            [2,20,80],
            [3,50,60],
            [4,70,80]
          ],    
 //jsonStr,
 //data;
 {
   rollPeriod: 7,
   showRoller: true
 }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `file` option to `updateOptions` to change the data in the chart, e.g.:

```js
$.get('/path/to/data', function(data) {
  g.updateOptions({file: data});
});
```

See the [dynamic update](http://dygraphs.com/tests/dynamic-update.html) demo for inspiration.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but that is not what i need. what i need is to combine dygraph + ajax.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to this answer, but just wrap the AJAX call around the Dygraph declaration (jQuery assumed here)

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {


var g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv"), data.rows, 
                     { 
//options 

}); 

})

// AJAX callbacks
.done(function() { console.log('getJSON request succeeded!'); })
```